# Android - how to make TextView fill_parent in code

Tags: java, android, fill-parent

I'm trying to make my TextView layout_width to be fill parent throw code.
this is my code:

```
 TextView WatchMovieTitle;

 private void PrintTheMovieAndYear() {
    if (CountWords() > 23) {
// this is what im doing wrong
 //             WatchMovieTitle.setLayoutParams
 //    (new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        WatchMovieTitle.setText(movieList.get("movieName") + " " + "("
                + movieList.get("movieYear") + ")");
        WatchMovieYear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        WatchMovieYear
                .setText(" " + "(" + movieList.get("movieYear") + ")");

    }
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 WatchMovieTitle.setLayoutParams(Params1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

or

```
LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

based on your textview's parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this 
assuming that you have called you TextView as tv

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```